# how to cotrol running windows service via console application c#

Tags: windows-services, console-application

i need a com, or batch file for config my server windows services, that will run on service failure, this file(or script) must get current failed service info include name, dependency, path,... and change this values, is it possible in any  programming language??
i'm try with batch file, and it's syntax is ambiguous, i am trying with .net console app , is there any class in .net for this problem??

like this dreamy code?!!  ;)

```
ServiceManager procMgr = new  ServiceManager ();
var service = procMgr.getCurrentFailureService();

if (service.logOnAs == serviceState.localsystem) { 
      service.logonAs = serviceState.NetworkService;          
  }
else if (service.logOnAs == serviceState.NetworkService){
service.logonAs = serviceState.localsystem; 
}
service.Restart();
writeLogFile();
```

Comment: Not sure what you were dreaming.  Use the ServiceController class.

Comment: and what's witch name Space?

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=servicecontroller+class

Comment: Tanx Alot, this class is benefit for server admins, but Service.property is read only,